# Bounded Context, Subdomains and Ubiquitous language

Tags: domain-driven-design

a) With BCs containing two or more subdomains there's a possibility of concepts overlapping and even worse, the same concept ( used by several of these subdomains ) may be interpreted/understood differently by each subdomain.

Regardless, if BC does contain numerous subdomains, should it provide several Ubiquitous languages, one for each subdomain, or should all subdomains share the same Ubiquitous language?

b) I assume when a single subdomain spans several BCs, each of these BCs should define its very own Ubiquitous language?

thanks

Comment: A UL is targeted at a BC.  So if there is a 1-1 mapping between a BC and a sub-domain then each sub-domain will have its own UL.  If a BC contains several sub-domains then, yes, the UL is also shared.

Comment: It is funny to ask because Ubiquitous does mean the same everywhere but yes UL is per BC

Comment: @Asher: I apologize for late reply, but I haven't noticed your answer

Comment: sub-domain is problem space and bounded context is solution space, but in general case they should be 1:1. For legacy code it is ok to have more than one bounded context per sub-domain, but NOT the other way arround - one bounded context should not cover more than one sub-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Although each domain and sub-domain may have its own language, the UL specifically targets the BC. A BC models the domain and barrows as much as possible from the already established domain language. It is called ubiquitous because it is used ubiquitously by the engineers and the domain experts, which unfortunately often cannot be said for the domain language itself.

B) Each BC should have its own UL.

When the BC models more than one (sub)domain with overlapping concepts it would be wise to consider splitting that BC. A shared kernel could be used to deduplicate the overlap that is equal in concept in both (sub)domains.

Comment: I feel like 1 entity per BC is a little bit over killing. You can perfectly have multiple aggregate roots (AG) in one BC. Each aggregate could easily have entities (not AG) in them as fields.

Comment: I agree with Tony. A BC is not at all defined by its number of entities, but by its responsibilities and definition. The blue book is also certainly not outdated in this respect.

Comment: @MattDavey you are confusing `Aggregate root` with `Bounded context`. These are totally NOT the same! And Bounded context should not cover more than one sub-domain.